# What software can I use to make fluid text 3D motion graphic?

Tags: video-editor, software-recommendation, motion-graphics

I want to be able to do at least this:

Someone told me "Could adobe after effects, if 3D camera mode was used, and then if text was added on path."

I at least I need to know what tools can assuredly do this before I start getting into courses for it.

A suggested workflow like the quote would be much appreciated as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was quite possibly made with After Effects.

You could learn how to make something pretty similar by following this old but good set of tutorials for beginners:

https://www.videocopilot.net/basic/

1. You could start by making a layer
2. Make sure the text is left aligned
3. Make it 3D
4. Duplicate it several times
5. Make a null object and place it on the left edge of your text layers
6. Parent the text layers to the null object
7. Rotate each of the text layers in 3D space
8. Then animate the rotation of the null object

[image: screengrab]